# How many tags can be subscribed for one client_id on Instagram?

Tags: tags, instagram, subscription, hashtag

Currently, Instagram limits me to subscribe only 4 tags for a client_id? If I subscribe 5th tags, it randomly deletes one and adds 5th one? Is there a known limit? I understand this question is not coding related but can not find anywhere in Instagram developer document, So perhaps this question will help community in general.