# Instagram not calling callback URL for certain tags

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I have subscribed to 14 hashtags in instagram. Callback URL is not been called for few hashtags. For other hashtags, it is calling callback URL. What could be the problem?

I checked in this API 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_secret=secret&client_id=client

All my 14 has been subscribed.But still the callback URL has been not called when I post something in Instagram for few hashtags.

Comment: Just looking into this now. No solution for you, but it looks like @NullException started a similar thread and found that you can only subscribe 4 hashtags: [how many tags can be subscribed for one client id on instagram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636801/how-many-tags-can-be-subscribed-for-one-client-id-on-instagram)